# Redirecting Subdomain to HTTPS WWW URL using Apache Virtual Host

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I was wondering how do you redirect a subdomain for both HTTP & HTTPS to a specific URL.

I want it to go from:

```
http://test.example.com to https://www.example.com/test
```

and

```
https://test.example/com to https://www.example.com/test
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out, as it is working for me.

[**Check this .htaccess code here**](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z]+)\.(example\.com) #checking domain and subdomain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%2/%1 [R=301,L] #redirecting
```